# How to set OnClickListener for CalendarView?

Tags: android

I have been developing some Android application and there is the following code:

```
    final CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView)layout.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarView.setClickable(true);
    calendarView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("event", "click");
    });
    calendarView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.e("event", "long click");
                return false;
            }

    });
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                    int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                Log.e("event", "datachanged");
            }

    });
```

I need to catch "OnClick" events, but I catch only "OnDataChange" events. I don't understand why. Please, help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing there are some subview's of the 'CalendarView' and it is on these that you can register an 'OnClickListener' and not on the 'CalendarView'.

Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) and see that it extends 'FrameLayout'.

Comment: I have just seen at this article, but I don't understand why can it help me?

Answer (score 0):

As calendar is a Dialog not view use
DialogInterface.OnClickListener not View.OnclickListener

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

OnGlobalLayoutListener will do the trick.

```
calendarView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                  //your code here
            }
        });
```